# Java RegEx Split Matches and include trailing chars

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm after some help with a regex that I can't get to work correctly, I've used a few online tools to test the patterns but with little success.

I need to split a string based on a pattern FS[0-9][0-9], but also include some trailing text which could be any length comma separated text and numbers.

For example: `FS01,a,b,c,d,1,2,3FS02,x,y,zFS03,some random text,123FS04,1`

Would need to be split into:

- `FS01,a,b,c,d,1,2,3`
- `FS02,x,y,z`
- `FS03,some random text,123`
- `FS04,1`

Comment: So, basically, you want `FSFollowedBySomething`

Comment: FSnumbernumber, followed by something

Comment: Oh.. then you could check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind and positive lookahead to get the splits.

```
String s = "FS01,a,b,c,d,1,2,3FS02,x,y,zFS03,some random text,123FS04,1";
String tok[] = s.split("(?<!^)(?=FS\\d{2})");
System.out.println(tok[0]);
System.out.println(tok[1]);
System.out.println(tok[2]);
System.out.println(tok[3]);
```

**Output:**

```
FS01,a,b,c,d,1,2,3
FS02,x,y,z
FS03,some random text,123
FS04,1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iQ7jZ0/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!^)` Negative lookbehind asserts that what preceding is not the start of the line.
- `(?=FS\\d{2})` Lookahead asserts that what following is `FS` followed by two digits. So it sets the matching marker just before to all the `FS\d\d` but not the one at the start.

Comment: I'd replace `(?=FS)` with `(?=FS\d{2})` to match the OP's requirements. And maybe you want to explain what the code does, for others that read this answer.

Comment: You can change your `println()` lines to `for (String token : tok) System.out.println(token);` for simpler and readable code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this REGEX :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "FS01,a,b,c,d,1,2,3FS02,x,y,zFS03,some random text,123FS04,1";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(FS.*?)(?=(FS|$))");
    // positive Lookahead. Captures groups starting with FS and ending upto another FS or end of String (denoted by $)
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
FS01,a,b,c,d,1,2,3
FS02,x,y,z
FS03,some random text,123
FS04,1
```

Comment: Changed the pattern to ((FS\d{2}).*?)(?=(FS|$)) and is exactly what im wanting thanks

Comment: @MattRoberts - Glad i could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex here `FS.*?(?=FS)`

http://www.regexr.com/3999u

Comment: doesn't match the last `FS`. i.e, `FS04,1`